# Migrate Apple Mail Mbox files to Google Apps for Work

Tags: email, google-apps-email, migrate-data

I've got a few clients using Apple Mail with large Mbox files. I need to upload 10Gb of old mail to Google Apps for Work. I was told that copying mail from locally saved mailboxes (in Apple Mail) to Google Apps using IMAP is unreliable and not recommended.

I know about google-email-uploader-mac but it is not longer available.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: See [Migrate mail using a Mac - Google Apps Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1366854?hl=en)